# vector<unique_ptr<A> > in constructor - error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++14, unique-ptr

I am passing a vector of `std::unique_ptr` of objects `A` as a parameter to a constructor of objects `Obj`. This is working when I use the `std::move` syntax as is shown below. However, if I add another object to the constructor's parameter list (the `mpq_class i` in the below code) I get an **error message** that reads

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> >'
```

on OS X and

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Interface; _Dp = std::default_delete<Interface>]’
```

on a linux system.

In the function `getVector()` the vector of `unique_ptr` is created, then passed to the `Obj` constructor and the objects are added to another vector and returned.

My **question** is why the code tries to call a copy constructor if I use `std::move` for the unique_ptrs and how to get rid of it!

**The code** that produces the error is shown below.

```
// g++ -Wall -O3 -std=c++1y -lgmpxx -lgmp
#include <vector>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A( int y ) : x(y) {}
    int x;  
};


class Obj {
public:
    Obj( mpq_class i, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A> > v ) : number(i), cont( std::move(v) ) {}

    mpq_class number;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A> > cont;
};


std::vector<Obj> getVector()
{
    std::vector<Obj> result;
    int M = 3, N = 5;

    for( int mm = 0; mm < M; mm++ )
    {
        mpq_class rational;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A> > abstractObjectsForConstructor;
        for(int nn = 0; nn < N; nn++ )
        {
            mpq_class r(mm,nn);
            rational = r;
            abstractObjectsForConstructor.push_back( std::make_unique<A>(nn) );
        }

        result.emplace_back( rational, std::move(abstractObjectsForConstructor) );
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Obj> vec = getVector();

    for( unsigned int ii = 0; ii < vec.size(); ii++ )
    {
        for( unsigned int jj = 0; jj < vec[ii].cont.size(); jj++ )
        {
            std::cout << vec[ii].cont[jj]->x << '\t' << std::endl;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The whole error message reads:

```
In file included from vector_unique.cpp:2:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:265:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__bit_reference:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:628:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1645:31: error: 
      call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> >'
            ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                              ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1572:18: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<A,
      std::__1::default_delete<A> > >::construct<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> >,
      std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> > &>' requested here
            {__a.construct(__p, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);}
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1453:14: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> > >
      >::__construct<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> >, std::__1::unique_ptr<A,
      std::__1::default_delete<A> > &>' requested here
            {__construct(__has_construct<allocator_type, pointer, _Args...>(),
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1005:25: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> > >
      >::construct<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> >, std::__1::unique_ptr<A,
      std::__1::default_delete<A> > &>' requested here
        __alloc_traits::construct(__a, _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(this->__end_), *__first);
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1203:9: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<A,
      std::__1::default_delete<A> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> > >
      >::__construct_at_end<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> > *>' requested here
        __construct_at_end(__x.__begin_, __x.__end_);
        ^
vector_unique.cpp:15:8: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<A,
      std::__1::default_delete<A> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> > >
      >::vector' requested here
        class Obj {
              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1572:18: note: 
      (skipping 2 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
            {__a.construct(__p, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);}
                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1535:17: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<Obj>
      >::construct<Obj, const Obj &>' requested here
                construct(__a, _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(__end2-1), _VSTD::move_if_noexcept(*--__end1));
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:874:21: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<Obj>
      >::__construct_backward<Obj *>' requested here
    __alloc_traits::__construct_backward(this->__alloc(), this->__begin_, this->__end_, __v.__begin_);
                    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1621:5: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<Obj, std::__1::allocator<Obj>
      >::__swap_out_circular_buffer' requested here
    __swap_out_circular_buffer(__v);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1639:9: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::vector<Obj, std::__1::allocator<Obj>
      >::__emplace_back_slow_path<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t> &, std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<A,
      std::__1::default_delete<A> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> > > > >'
      requested here
        __emplace_back_slow_path(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
        ^
vector_unique.cpp:40:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::vector<Obj,
      std::__1::allocator<Obj> >::emplace_back<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t> &, std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<A,
      std::__1::default_delete<A> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> > > > >'
      requested here
                        result.emplace_back( rational, std::move(abstractObjectsForConstructor) );
                               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2515:31: note: 
      copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> >' has a
      user-declared move constructor
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& __u) _NOEXCEPT
                              ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: `std::make_unique<A>( A(nn) )` should be `std::make_unique<A>(nn)`

Comment: @Matt: Sorry, changed that. But the error disappears if I comment `result.emplace_back( rational, std::move(abstractObjectsForConstructor) );` - when the constructor for `Obj` is called

Comment: Show the whole error message. Every major compiler lists the line number with an error message. Tell us which line of your code corresponds to the line number in the error.

Comment: Are you sure that `mpq_class` is movable? (if not, then `Obj` would not be movable)

Comment: If I create a dummy mpq_class, gcc 5.1.0 compiles this code without errors. What compiler do you use?

Comment: @MattMcNabb it complains about `unique_ptr<A>` so i should not be related to `Obj`

Comment: @MattMcNabb No I'm not sure if it's movable..

Comment: @Slava I am using Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn (whatever that means :S) on OS X and g++ 5.1.0 on Linux

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem without using gmp, so I guess it is something about mpq_class.

Comment: Try putting the gmp headers after all the standard headers (that's good practice in case they define a macro that doesn't respect standard name requirements for macros)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Putting the headers at the end doesn't change the error message. But you might be right in that the error occurs due to gmp. Exchanging the `mpq_class` variable via some custom class `B` compiles perfectly.

Comment: I deleted my answer saying `mpq_class` is not moveable, because even though that appears to be the cause of your error, I didn't notice [these lines](https://github.com/AlexeiSheplyakov/gmp.pkg/blob/master/gmpxx.h#L1642-L1645) in gmpxx.h. Maybe your problem is that [`__GMPXX_USE_CXX11`](https://github.com/AlexeiSheplyakov/gmp.pkg/blob/master/gmpxx.h#L44-L51) is not being set correctly?

Comment: @Praetorian You're right - I didn't know about `__GMPXX_USE_CXX11` either. Considering the current results it might be the solution! I'm not sure where I need to define the constant. Do I need to set `#define __GMPXX_USE_CXX11 1` in my program (before including the gmp headers) or directly in `gmpxx.h`? Unfortunately, the first option doesn't change the error message.

Comment: @seyfe definitely you should put that define into your source (before gmpxx.h is included). If it does not work you may have version of gmp older than what is referenced in git, then you either need to upgrade or specify move ctor for Obj explicitly

Comment: If I add the constructor `Obj( Obj&& other) { number = other.number; cont = std::move(other.cont) ;}` the code compiles! (With or without defining `__GMPXX_USE_CXX11`) Is this the right way to implement the `move` constructor or did I miss anything?

Comment: @seyfe Adding `#define __GMPXX_USE_CXX11 1` to your example above before including any other headers should get the code to compile. You could also define your own move constructor, but it shouldn't be necessary since gmpxx seems to support C++11. Even the `#define` isn't required because invoking the compiler with `-std=c++11` or greater should automatically define that. Have you actually compared the contents of your gmpxx.h to the one I linked above? Maybe you have an older version?

Comment: @Praetorian I checked on both systems if the part starting with `#if __GMPXX_USE_CXX11` exists in the gmp header files - and it does exist.

Comment: I'm sorry - I really appreciated your help; it gave a lot of insight into the topic, but I felt exhausted and in the end I gave up on using `unique_ptr`s and started using `shared_ptr` instead -.-

Answer (score 9):

Culprit is `mpq_class`. With simple dummy version it compiles fine (I commented out headers for gmp) :

```
struct mpq_class {
   mpq_class() {}
   mpq_class( int, int );
};
```

However, when you make that class not movable:

```
struct mpq_class {
   mpq_class() {}
   mpq_class( int, int );
   mpq_class( const mpq_class & ) {}
   mpq_class( mpq_class && ) = delete;

   mpq_class &operator=( const mpq_class & ) {return *this;}
};
```

Your problem comes back.

So issue that if `mpq_class` is not movable then `Obj` is not movable either and usage of `emplace_back` implicitly generates code to copy `Obj` in case of relocation which fails to compile because `std::unique_ptr<A>` is not copyable.

Answer (score -3):

[wrong, see below]

The problem is with the definition of the Obj constructor. Its second argument is passed by value, which results in a copy being made. The fact that you use std::move in the initializer list does not change this fact.

The remedy is to use an rvalue reference for the second argument of the Obj constructor.

Comment: I'm not too sure about this - if I declare a constructor argument "by value" and pass it in an rvalue-reference I sure hope it gets move constructed and not copied as you say. Consider the current guideline of passing `std::string` by value - it will copy when it needs to ( if you pass in an lvalue) and get move constructed when you pass in a temporary.